# automatically compare results of two cnn models in keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm following this blog post :
https://yashk2810.github.io/Applying-Convolutional-Neural-Network-on-the-MNIST-dataset/
and using the model there to work with my data.

The keras model used is :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

# Fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10))

model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Say above is Model A, having batch Normalization, and Model B is replica of Model A but without Batch Normalization.

I have 15 test files for which I'm calculating precision recall accuracy etc.
Currently I'm training Model A noting down results that appear on the terminal, and then training Model B and noting those results and comparing.

Is there a way to automatically save the results from both models to a tabular format so that I can easily compare how the various metrics differ in both cases?

is it not very important but , 
The structure I have in mind is something like an R dataframe

```
Filename  |  Model | Metric1 | Metric2  
a              A       90%      80%
b              A       60%      90%
a              B       70%      81%
```

Thank you.

PS : just to be clear, I know that I can save results from each run to a list/dict and then reshape it as I want.

My question, If i declare 3-4 models, how do I compare the performance automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know how to compare the models automatically, but one usually uses the ROC curves to compare classifiers. I suggest you to read Fawcett's paper on ROC analysis. You can request it on ResearchGate.

[ROC Analysis](https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/publication/222511520_Introduction_to_ROC_analysis/amp)

With binary classifiers, one calculates the true-positive-rate and the false-positive-rate for all possible thresholds and plots the first on the y-axis and the second on the x-axis. The resulting curve per classifier can be integrated and the resulting integral, the so called "area under the curve", is equal to the probability that the classifier rankes a randomly chosen positive sample higher than a randomly chosen negative one. This value can be used to compare classifiers because a higher value shows a overall better performance than a lower one. Fawcett also gives a method to apply this to multi-class classification.